# Mockito when creating object is from private method of other class

Tags: java, mockito

I have a problem, like below, In my test code I want to test "needTest" function from class A. However, needTest function created a db connector in its private method and then use that connector to connect DB.

I want to mock createObjB but it is a private function.
I want to mock Connector's connectDB but the object is created inside needTest which seeme I can't intervene.

So my question is, do I have to make createObjB public?

```
package AProblem;


import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

public class Connector {
    public void connectDB() {
        // This function connects DB
    }
}

public class A {
    private Connector createObjB() {
        return new Connector();
    }

    public void needTest() {
        Connector connector = createObjB();
        connector.connectDB();
        // do something else
    }
}


@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestA {
    @InjectMocks
    private A a;

    @Test
    public void testNeedTest() {
        // I need to mock connector, but I can't access createObjB
        // How can I stub a fake Connector somewhere so that connectDB() will not access DB?
    }

}
```

Comment: you need to use powermockito . Mockito cannot do this. Give it a try with Powermock

Comment: What exactly do you need to mock the created connector for? Posting some test code that would need it to be mocked would be helpful.

Comment: A) you can't mock `new()` using Mockito. You need PowerMock(ito) or JMockit for that B) you wrote hard to test code. Instead of bending over backwards using other frameworks, the real answer is to improve your production code. Make it *not* hard to test. For example by not calling `new()` directly. Read about dependency injection for example.